# Codeception tests failure after upgrading to 2.1

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel, laravel-5, codeception

I have over 1400 codeception tests for Laravel 5.1 application I develop at the moment. I've been used Codeception 2.0.15. But today I've moved to Codeception 2.1.2. I've updated `api.suite.yml` and other suite configuration files but many tests are failing now.

First thing I've noticed is that data in memcached are no longer cleared after tests so tests at the moment affect each other. But it's not only that. In one of tests I run something like that:

```
public function tryToCompareClient(UnitTester $I)
{
    $data = [
        'client1' => [
            'id' => 500,
            'option1' => 'yes',
        ],
        'client2' => [
            'id' => 600,
            'option2' => 'no',
        ],
    ];

    Config::set('crm_settings.clients', $data);

    $crm = App::make('crm');

    $I->assertTrue($crm->isClient('client1', $data['client1']['id']));
    // ...
```

When I run only this test it's working fine but when I run multiple a group of tests, this test will fail because `crm` is singleton in my application and it seems that when I set new config in above tests, this class is not loading data from config each time but only when it's not set. It seems that something has been changed in Codeception/Laravel5 module so `App` instance is being reused between tests.

At the moment I assume those problems are affected by refactor in [this commit](https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/commit/c356f391bbf97d9ed772db04b9f6841987f3373e) but the question is - is there any easy way to make Codeception to work as before 2.1.2 or maybe the only way is using old 2.0 branch for such functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there was a bug in 2.1 branch. It doesn't work in 2.1.4 either. After setting version in `composer.json` to `2.1.x-dev` it started working.

However 2.1 branch has also other issues:

- not clearing cache after each test
- problem with MySQL too many connections error when running lots of tests

so at the moment I recommend anyone who want to use `2.1` branch for Laravel using `2.0` branch instead until all problems will be fixed.

You might also [track this discussion](https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/issues/2559#issuecomment-162815538) for further details.

**EDIT**

I can confirm those issues were solved in latest `2.1.x-dev` so now everything seems to be working as in 2.0 branch